# Fama and French Three Factors: A time series analysis

Tags: time-series, references

Is there any literature on whether the three factors in the [Fama–French three-factor model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fama%E2%80%93French_three-factor_model) follow any kind of time series models, such as multivariate ARMA?